# jquery toggle buttons

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a list of items which have an open /close button next to each of them.  I would like to toggle the open / close buttons.  This seems to be work the first time the button is selected but then the function isn't initiated the second time the button is selected.  Anyone know why?

```
    //update status - close
    $("#close_<?=$order_id?>").click(function(){
        alert('close');
        order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
        order_status = '2';
        order_selected.set("status", order_status); 
        $("#close_<?=$order_id?>").replaceWith('<a data-align="left" class="km-button" data-role="button" id="open_<?=$order_id?>" style="float:left; margin:5px;"><span class="km-text">Re-open</span></a>');      
      });         

//update status - re-open
    $("#open_<?=$order_id?>").click(function(){
        alert('open');
        order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
        order_status = '1';
        $("#open_<?=$order_id?>").replaceWith('<a data-align="left" class="km-button" data-role="button" id="close_<?=$order_id?>" style="float:left; margin:5px;"><span class="km-text">Close</span></a>');            
      });
```

Comment: This is just a first guess and I may be wrong but you can try replacing `.click(function(){ ... });` with `.live('click', function(){ ... });` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than .click you must use .live because click only works for elements in the DOM at the time of setting up the click event. The live subscription looks for DOM updates also.

```
    //update status - close
    $("#close_<?=$order_id?>").live('click',function(){
        alert('close');
        order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
        order_status = '2';
        order_selected.set("status", order_status); 
        $("#close_<?=$order_id?>").replaceWith('<a data-align="left" class="km-button" data-role="button" id="open_<?=$order_id?>" style="float:left; margin:5px;"><span class="km-text">Re-open</span></a>');      
      });         

    //update status - re-open
    $("#open_<?=$order_id?>").live('click',function(){
        alert('open');
        order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
        order_status = '1';
        $("#open_<?=$order_id?>").replaceWith('<a data-align="left" class="km-button" data-role="button" id="close_<?=$order_id?>" style="float:left; margin:5px;"><span class="km-text">Close</span></a>');            
      });
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, and you forgot the event handler name as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks, its updated now. Good point about the live being deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Because 'click' is only binded to the first element, which you're replacing.

The brute force solution would be to use live('click', function..) instead of click(function..)

However, my recommendations:

1. Create a class, like 'orderbutton'
2. bind the click to that class, with live if necessary
3. regain the order ID from javascript - never generate javascript code from PHP (except for JSON)
4. create a 'collapsed' version which is originally hidden - remember, it needs to have a different ID (perhaps you should use data attribute instead of the ID attribute)
5. move all your style definition to classes instead of inline *style*

**edit:**

Recommended HTML:

```
<a data-align="left" data-orderId="<?$order_id?>" 
    class="km-button orderbutton closed" 
    data-role="button" 
    id="open_<?=$order_id?>">
        <span class="km-text reopen">Re-open</span>
        <span class="km-text close">close</span>
</a>
```

Recommended CSS file:

```
.orderbutton {
   float:left; 
   margin:5px;
}
.orderbutton.closed .close {
   display:none;
}
.orderbutton.open .reopen {
   display: none;
}
```

Recommended JS:

```
$('a.orderbutton').live('click', function(){
    var order_id = $(this).data('orderId');
    var is_closed = ($(this).hasClass('closed');
    order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
    order_status = is_closed ? '2' : '1';
    order_selected.set("status", order_status); 


    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
         $(this).removeClass('closed');
         $(this).addClass('open');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('open')){
         $(this).removeClass('open');
         $(this).addClass('closed');
    }
});
```

Or, in shorter form:

```
$('a.orderbutton').live('click', function(){
    var order_id = $(this).data('orderId');
    var is_closed = ($(this).hasClass('closed');
    order_update_type = 'updatestatus';
    order_status = is_closed ? '2' : '1';
    order_selected.set("status", order_status); 

    $(this).toggleClass('open', $(this).hasClass('closed');
    $(this).toggleClass('closed', $(this).hasClass('open');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, howevr, being quite new to JQuery, Im a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

As you are replacing the elements, you should delegate the *click* event, try the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#close_<?=$order_id?>", function(){
     // ...      
}); 

$(document).on("click", "#open_<?=$order_id?>", function(){
     // ...      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use jquery [slidetoggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$("#first").slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points (Mostly extending Aadaam's):

1. Don't generate the JavaScript with the order number hard-coded into the selector - as a matter of fact don't put the order number into the id at all, otherwise you'll be to unnecessarily repeating the same code for each button.
2. Since the open and close buttons are identical save the id (which you shouldn't be using like that as in point 1) and the text, don't replace the button but just toggle the text and a class as a marker:

(NB: Don't hard code styles and the class on the inner span seems unneccerery. You can select it in CSS using `km-buttom > span` instead.)

Example:

```
<a data-align="left" class="km-button" data-role="button" data-order-id="<?=$order_id?>" class="closed"><span>Re-open</span></a>

$('.km-button').click(function() { 
  var $this = $(this);
  var orderId = $this.data('order-id'); // Get Order id if you need it for something
  if ($this.hasClass('closed')) {
    // Do what needed
    $this.find('span').text('Close');
  } else {
    // Do what needed
    $this.find('span').text('Re-open');
  }
  $this.toggleClass('closed');
});
```

I'm assuming all your order buttons have the class `.km-button` to select them all at once. 
You may need an alternative e.g. an attribute selector `[data-order-id]`.